# spring boot mongodb xml configuration

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure mongoClient using xml configuration in a spring boot application.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mongodb.MongoCredential' for property 'credentials[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

**Spring Configuration file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" credentials="user:password@testdb"></mongo:mongo-client>

</beans>
```

The spring-data-mongodb [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.10.0.M1/reference/html/) also mentions about the credentials field in xml configuration.  Not sure if I'm missing any dependencies or should I have to add some custom mapping converters.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.vjso</groupId>
    <artifactId>Gyaan</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.12</lombok.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.22</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.8</logback.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.5.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Hopper-SR7</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the file: src\main\resources\application.properties

## MONGODB (MongoProperties)

```
spring.data.mongodb.host= # the db host
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 # the connection port (defaults to 27107)
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test # connection URL
spring.data.mongodb.database=
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=
spring.data.mongodb.grid-fs-database=
spring.data.mongodb.username=
spring.data.mongodb.password=
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true # if spring data repository support is enabled
```

From [Source Cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538123/spring-boot-and-mongodb-configuration)

**Will Edit Post**

If you really want the xml configuation. I will post once I find a solution

Comment: Yes, I'm able to avoid that error with MongoClient by adding thespring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependency and removing the xml configuration, This way, we can use MongoRepository and can avoid using the MongoClient. However, I was thinking if we really want to use a MongoClient, how can that be done.  May be a Bean definition in java configuration might solve this.  Need to check that.